# Server Hard drive Upgrade/ Swap

Tags: hdd

Good morning everyone,
My server at work has hit its ceiling with only 300mb left.
Can I just switch out old hdd's for new?
The Storage rack is a Netgear ReadyNas 4200.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have pc building experience none with servers.
Thanks,
CB.

Comment: How could we know with next to zero information?

Comment: 300 *millibits* sounds a bit small...

Comment: If you need any further information I will gladly get it.

Comment: Like I said I'm new to the server world and any direction is appreciated.

Comment: I would rather look at getting a nvme system rather than putting in bigger SATA drives.

Comment: This would purely be a for a temporary fix. the company intends to switch to SharePoint in the near future. This would be to alleviate any issues in the immediate.

Comment: We need many more details. What kind of server? What kind of hard drive? What kind of hard drive controller? RAID? OS drive or data drive? Etc., etc.

Comment: Would photos of the server rack as well as model numbers for individual pieces help?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I just switch out old hdd's for new?

No.

That's not a server anyway, it's a NAS.

Get a professional in, that's who this site's for.